# How to find the limit of $g_n$ which $g_n(t)=e^{t-1}g_{n-1}(1-(1-p)(1-t))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> How to compute the $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(t)$, which $$g_n(t)=e^{t-1}g_{n-1}\big(1-(1-p)(1-t)\big)$$
>   where $g_0=1$, $t>0$, $0<p<1$, $n\geq 1$.

I cannot find the recursion of the $g_n$. Is there any other method to approach?

Comment: Where are the $g_n$'s defined? $f(t) = 1-(1-p)(1-t) = p + (1-p)t$ is a convex combination of $1$ and $t$, if this helps. I think you should consider what happens to $f^n(t) = (f\circ\ldots\circ f)(t)$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$. Start with $p=1/2$.

Comment: @amsmath Actually, $g_n(t):=\mathbb{E}(t^{X_{n}})$. But there is no condition about the $X_n$. So ..

Comment: @amsmath Why consider $f^n(t)$?

Comment: Because $g_n(t) = e^{t-1}g_{n-1}(f(t)) = e^{t-1}e^{f(t)-1}g_{n-2}(f^2(t)) = \ldots$.

Comment: For $p=1/2$ you have $f^n(t) = 1+\frac{t-1}{2^n}$ and $g_n(t) = e^{2(t-1)(1-2^{-n})}\to e^{2(t-1)}$.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks. I know the iteration of $f^n$ if $p=1/2$. But how about the general $p$?

Comment: @amsmath Ok. Is it $f^n(t)=1+(1-p)^n(t-1)$?

Comment: Yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(t) = p + (1-p)t$. Then $f^k(t) = 1+(1-p)^k(t-1)$. You can priove that by induction if you want. Moreover,
\begin{align}
g_n(t)
&= e^{t-1}g_{n-1}(f(t)) = e^{t-1}e^{f(t)-1}g_{n-2}(f^2(t)) = \ldots\\
&= e^{t-1}e^{f(t)-1}e^{f^2(t)-1}\dots e^{f^{n-1}(t)-1}g_0(f^n(t))\\
&= e^{t-1}e^{f(t)-1}e^{f^2(t)-1}\dots e^{f^{n-1}(t)-1}\\
&= \exp\left(t-n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f^k(t)\right)\\
&= \exp\left(t-n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[1+(1-p)^k(t-1)]\right)\\
&= \exp\left((t-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-p)^k\right)\\
&= \exp\left((t-1)\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{p}\right)\\
&= e^{(t-1)/p}\cdot e^{-(t-1)(1-p)^n/p},
\end{align}
which tends to $g(t) = e^{(t-1)/p}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer!